# Access Violation after creating GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having access violation on every gl call after this texture initialization (actually the last `GLCALL(glBindTexture(m_Target, bound));` is also causing access violation so the code at the top is what probably causing it):

```
Texture2D::Texture2D(unsigned int format, unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int unit, unsigned int mimapLevels, unsigned int layers)
        : Texture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, unit)
    {
        unsigned int internalFormat;
        if (format == GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT)
        {
            internalFormat = GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32;
        }
        else
        {
            internalFormat = format;
        }
        m_Format = format;
        m_Width = width;
        m_Height = height;
        unsigned int bound = 0;
        glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D_ARRAY, (int*)&bound);
        GLCALL(glGenTextures(1, &m_ID));
        GLCALL(glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + m_Unit));
        GLCALL(glBindTexture(m_Target, m_ID));
        GLCALL(glTexParameteri(m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
        GLCALL(glTexParameteri(m_Target, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
        GLCALL(glTexStorage3D(m_Target, mimapLevels, internalFormat, width, height, layers));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < layers; i++)
        {
            glTexSubImage3D(m_Target, 0, 0, 0, i, m_Width, m_Height, 1, m_Format, s_FormatTypeMap[internalFormat], NULL);
        }
        GLCALL(glBindTexture(m_Target, bound));
    }
```

OGL pointers are initialized with glad at the beginning of the program:

```
        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
```

And this only happens with `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`, even when this is the first line of my code (after initialization of-course), example code:

```
auto t = Texture2D(GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 1024, 10, 1, 4);
```

Any idea what may be causing it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a `NULL` for the last argument of `glTexSubImage3D`, but OpenGL does not allow that:

> **TexSubImage*D** and **TextureSubImage*D** arguments *width*, *height*, *depth*, *format*, *type*, and *data* match the corresponding arguments to the corresponding **TexImage*D** command (where those arguments exist), meaning that they accept the same values, and have the same meanings. **The exception is that a `NULL` *data* pointer does not represent unspecified image contents.**

...and there's no text that allows a `NULL` pointer, therefore you cannot pass `NULL`.

It's unclear what you're trying to achieve with those `glTexSubImage3D` calls. Since you're using an immutable texture (`glTexStorage3D`) you don't need to do anything extra. If instead you want to clear your texture then you can use `glClearTexSubImage` which **does accept `NULL` for *data*** to means 'clear with zeros'.